# can HAProxy process flow-control by session?

Tags: tcp, haproxy, flow-control

about HAProxy in tcp mode.I want set a limit to the number of packets go through session per second,say 400 packets/s.Is it possible to make it by set up some rules in config file? If not, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

o I see.it is possible.mention in link below:
http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/02/27/use-a-load-balancer-as-a-first-row-of-defense-against-ddos/